# PHP to redirect after athorization

Tags: facebook, redirect, authorization

Need some help writing a php page to either pass them into the app if they approve the extended permissions or redirect to another page if they don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if ($_SESSION['decision'] == 'agreed') {
    header("Location: pageAfterAgree.php");
  } else {
    header("Location: pageAfterDisagree.php");
  }
?>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by $conditiomet? How do I set up $conditiomet in the php to check the session?

Comment: Yes, the $conditionmet could be a session variable.